# Got wrong date when converting string date retrieved from the api

Tags: api, date, datetime, google-apps-script

I'm calling an API to get some dates, but the API returns the date in string format so I'm using new Date() to convert it to date format, the problem is that after the conversion I'm getting a wrong date

For example new Date("2019-04-19") is returning Thu Apr 18 19:00:00 GMT-05:00 2019

this is my code

```
function HebrewCalAPI(fechas) 
{
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.hebcal.com/hebcal/?v=1&cfg=json&maj=on&min=on&mod=on&nx=on&year=now&month=x&ss=on&mf=on&c=on&geo=geoname&geonameid=3530597&m=50&s=on");

  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  var arrayEmpiezan = []

  for(var i in fechas)
  {
    for(var i2 in data.items)
    {
      if(data.items[i2].title == fechas[i])
      {
        arrayEmpiezan.push(new Date(data.items[i2].date));
      }
    }
  }

  return arrayEmpiezan
}

var fiestasEmpiezan = ["Erev Pesach","Pesach VI (CH''M)","Erev Shavuot","Erev Rosh Hashana","Erev Yom Kippur","Erev Sukkot","Sukkot VII (Hoshana Raba)"]
var fiestasAcaban = ["Pesach II", "Pesach VIII","Shavuot II","Rosh Hashana II","Yom Kippur","Sukkot II","Simchat Torah"]

var FiestaEmpieza = date
var FiestaAcaba = date
FiestaEmpieza = HebrewCalAPI(fiestasEmpiezan)
FiestaAcaba = HebrewCalAPI(fiestasAcaban)
```

Any help please ?

Comment: What's the problem? Why do you think that Apr 18 19:00 GMT-5 is different than Apr 19 00:00 GMT ?

Comment: I should get Apr 19 , not 18

Comment: Quoting tehhowch, Why do you think that "``Apr 18 19:00 GMT-5``" is different than "``Apr 19 00:00 GMT``" ?

Comment: @sath It might help if you answer this question: what is the fundamental unit of the JavaScript `Date` object? Year? Month? Day? Hour? Minute? Second? Millisecond? Microsecond? Nanosecond? What does `Date(0)` mean?